# TestFlight feedback page doesn't extend all the way on iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, feedback, testflight

We're using the latest TestFligth SDK (1.1) but the feedback page doesn't extend all the way on iPhone 5 screen and remains at the same size as it would on iPhone 4 screen. Anyone knows why this is happening and how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: you should ask TestFlight support directly http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/emails/new

Comment: I've already requested support on their website but no response yet. So I thought some one might be able to help here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got a response back from TestFlight team and they haven't fixed the feedback page for iPhone 5 screen size yet in case any one needs to know. You can create your own form and use submitCustomFeedback.